# How Web notification knows the right device to send the notification to

Tags: push-notification

This thing is ticking in the back of my head since long time ago, i searched a lot and couldn't find answer,
when push noticition server like onesignal sends a push notification, how does it know the right device to deliver the notification, how does it know it's IP address?
thank you.